# Need to call c# method after jquery dialog form is valid

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

My problem i dont know how to invoke a method after filled(textbox) and clicked btn in jquery dialog. Then i fill textbox in that dialog, i want to invoke method addClient in server code(aspx.cs file), which needs to get parameter as textbox.text value from dialog. I think i need proper ajax or something. Thanks for help!

My codes:

PartForm.aspx

```
     <script>
        $(function () {
        ClientName = $("#tbClientName");
        tips = $(".validateTips");

        function updateTips(t) {
            tips
              .text(t)
              .addClass("ui-state-highlight");
            setTimeout(function () {
                tips.removeClass("ui-state-highlight", 1500);
            }, 500);
        }

        function checkLength(o, n, min, max) {
            if (o.val().length > max || o.val().length < min) {
                o.addClass("ui-state-error");
                updateTips("Length of " + n + " must be between " +
                  min + " and " + max + ".");
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
     $('#newClient').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            draggable: true,
            title: "Pridėti užsakovą",
            open: function (type, data) {
                $(this).parent().appendTo();
            },
            buttons: {
                "Create an account": function () {
                    var bValid = true;
                    ClientName.removeClass("ui-state-error");
                    bValid = bValid && checkLength(ClientName, "Užsakovo pavadinimas", 3, 16);

                    if (bValid) {
                        // on alert im getting ClientName value which i need to use in addClient method as parameter
                        //alert(ClientName.val());
                        // tried a lot methods but didnt succeded, i need some code here if form is valid, somehow call addClient(ClientName.val());
                        //__doPostBack('AddClient', ClientName.val());
                        //$(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            },
        });
    });

    function showDialog(id) {
        $('#' + id).dialog("open");
    }

    function closeDialog(id) {
        $('#' + id).dialog("close");
    }

</script>

<input id="btnOpenClientAddForm" type="button" value="Pridėti užsakovą" onclick="showDialog('newClient');" />
<asp:Label ID="lblStatusAddClient" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<div id='newClient'>
<asp:Label ID="lblClientName" runat="server" Text="Užsakovo pavadinimas:"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="tbClientName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>
</div>
```

Server side code:

PartForm.aspx.cs

```
    public void AddClient(string ClientName)
    {
        string message;
        Class.DB.AddClient(ClientName, out message);
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
        {
            lblStatusAddClient.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
            lblStatusAddClient.Text = "Užsakovas pridėtas";
            upClients.Update();
        }
        else
        {
            lblStatusAddClient.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            lblStatusAddClient.Text = message;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PartForm.aspx**

In PartForm.aspx make ajax call to the web method in code behind.

```
if(bValid){
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "PartForm.aspx/AddClient",        
                data: JSON.stringify({ClientName: name }),
                async: false,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {

                       if(msg.d==''){
                         $('#lblStatusAddClient').css('color', 'green');
                         $('#lblStatusAddClient').text('Užsakovas pridėtas');
                       }

                       else{
                         $('#lblStatusAddClient').css('color', 'red');
                         $('#lblStatusAddClient').text(msg.d);
                      }                        

                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)["Message"]);
                }
            });
        }
```

**PartForm.aspx.cs**

Web methods have to be static. [Here](http://encosia.com/why-do-aspnet-ajax-page-methods-have-to-be-static/) you can find explanation why.

Since you can not access controls in webmethod, you'll have to change labels text and color in ajax success callback function.

```
   [WebMethod]
    public static string AddClient(string ClientName)
        {
        string message;
        Class.DB.AddClient(ClientName, out message);            

        return message;

    }
```

Comment: Getting Error message : Invalid JSON primitive:object, if took into data  data: "{'ClientName':" + ClientName + "}", and if i take  data: "{'ClientName':" + ClientName.val() + "}" getting Invalid JSON primitive: with text value of textbox

Comment: DB data inserted with method AddClient, but this code part doesnt work : function (msg) {

                       if(mgs.d==''){
                         $('#lblStatusAddClient').css('color', 'green');
                         $('#lblStatusAddClient').text('Užsakovas pridėtas');
                       }

                       else{
                         $('#lblStatusAddClient').css('color', 'red');
                         $('#lblStatusAddClient').text(msg.d);
                      }                        

                },

Comment: You have to be more precise. What's not working? What do you get as a response (msg.d)?

Comment: I`m getting msg.d as empty message, so it have to use, but label text doenst change: if(mgs.d==''){ $('#lblStatusAddClient').css('color', 'green'); $('#lblStatusAddClient').text('Užsakovas pridėtas');

Comment: Try : $('[id*="lblStatusAddClient"]').css('color', 'green'); $('[id*="lblStatusAddClient"]').text('Užsakovas pridėtas');

Comment: huh, just found mistake : mgs instead msg in your code :))